# Windows Server 2008 Remote Management cannot connect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, winrm, windows

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 running on a remote machine, with Windows 7 Ultimate as my client machine.

I followed the instructions here (http://www.petri.co.il/remote-management-in-windows-server-2008-r2.htm) to set up remote management.

However, when I open Server Manager > Action > Connect to Another Computer and enter my remote servers IP address, I get the following error

> Connecting to a remote server failed with the following error: The WinRM client cannot process the request.

I am used to managing Linux servers, where a simple host/user/password combination usually suffices. Is there something fundamental about Windows Server remote management I am missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** The thing you were trying to set up is a tool to manage multiple servers on *one* server, not to remotely manage your server.

<s>It's not really clear what you are trying to do... Manage your server from your client, or manage your client from your server?</s>

But if you want to manage your server from your client, then you need to setup Remote Desktop access:

### On your sever

[image: Configure Remote Desktop]

[image: Allow connections]

Then click `OK`

### On your client

- Open `Remote Desktop Connection`

  - Either `Start` > `Run` > type `mstsc` enter
  - or navigate `Start` > `All Programs` > `Accessories` > `Remote Desktop Connection`
- Type IP adress of the server
- Connect
- You probably have to authenticate

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can connect successfully to Remote Desktop from my client, but I still get the same error when I try to use Server Manager from my client to connect to the server

Comment: The Server Manager is actually a tool _to be run on servers_. If you want to modify something on the server, do it on the server itself, which you now can do easy with Remote Desktop.

Comment: You're welcome. I know it's not that easy to get into Windows servers when you're used to Linux servers..

Comment: @GeenHenk The Server Manager console is an MMC snapin like any other, and it can indeed be used to remotely manage other 2008 Servers withou having to remote desktop in. I think this is what the original question was getting at. It can be run from a Windows 7 client with the Remote Server Administration Tools pack installed.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the Server Manager console to work remotely can be a bit of a pain to get right.

Depending on what it is that you need to do, you might have more luck using the individual MMC snapins for the features that you want to administer. Provided the user account that you're running the consoles as have sufficient rights on the remote server, and there are no firewall rules blocking the traffic, it should be easier than jumping through the hoops that Server Manager seems to need.

Comment: Is there a straightforward guide to connecting Server Manager from a Windows 7 client to a Windows Server 2008 SP2 machine? Remote Desktop works fine for this purpose, but it would be great to not need a full desktop for basic management

Comment: I've personally not come across one, but then I've not looked either. Why not just create your own MMC console and add the snapins that are relevant to what you need to do on the remote server? You'll probably find that will work without any tweaking at all, provided there are no firewalls blocking the traffic.

Comment: I downloaded RSAT with the expectation of being able to do just that yet it wouldn't connect for various reasons. Hopefully I'll find a solution out there that's as simple as Remote Desktop, but only requires the use of RSAT Server Manager

Comment: Did you try any of the other MMC snapins, such as DNS, DHCP ADUC (depending on what is actually running on your remote server)? They don't require the amount of tweaking that the Server Manager does, and if they don't work either then the problem is either authentication or firewall related.

Comment: I have Hyper-V Manager on my Windows 7 Machine. In my hosts file I have an entry that maps SERVER-VPS to my servers IP address. When I try and connect, I get "Cannot connect to the RPC service on computer [IP Address]. Make sure your RPC service is running". I followed the instructions at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote (both workgroup?) yet I am still unable to connect. What, in your experience, would be a starting place for me to look at?

Comment: As above, authentication (is the user account that you're running the console as valid on the server?), or firewalls.